# Jquery Colorbox with a draggable event?

Tags: jquery, draggable, colorbox, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to implement on my [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) popup a draggable option. Is anyone came across this before?
I already use [Ui draggabl](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)e in case.

This **eg.** below show how to use it with jScrollPane as well.

```
    $('#TGB .terms-conditions').colorbox({
        width: 466,
        height: 526,
        inline: true,
        'opacity': 0.6,
        onComplete: function () {
            $('#cboxLoadedContent').jScrollPane({animateTo: true});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

this is the solution:

I used UI JQUERY

$('#colorbox').draggable();

Comment: Yes this works, but we need to set containment also like this: $('#colorbox').draggable({ containment: 'document' });

Comment: If my colorbox has a scrollbar (vert or hor), when clicking on scrollbar and scrolling, it scrolls, but when leaving the scrollbar, my colorbox moves with the mouse on the screen as if my mouse key is still down. Does anyone came across this before?

Comment: do you need to add to script code for draggable to work?